# call jquery plugin in another jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-plugins

I need to call jQuery plugin method from another jQuery function. I am using ASP.NET MVC5 and I have bundle my custom jQuery files within it, but for some reason is not working out.

### Jquery Main Function (mainCustomScript.js)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(this).greenify();
```

})

### jQuery Plugin  (DashboardGUI.js)

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.greenify = function () {
    alert("Hello it works");
};

})(jQuery);
```

### ASP.NET Bundle

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/CustomScripts").Include(
                                     "~/Scripts/Custom_Scripts/mainCustomScript.js"
                                     ));
```

### HTML

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/CustomScripts")
```

Comment: Where are you referring DashboardGUI.js file?

Comment: do i need this in bundle?

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue, as the plugin is always instantiated after it's loaded anyway (IIFE comes before DOM ready), but you do need to load both files.

Comment: sorry my bad, it works as the way you just said.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

answer

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/CustomScripts").Include(
                                     "~/Scripts/Custom_Scripts/DashboardGUI.js",
                                     "~/Scripts/Custom_Scripts/mainCustomScript.js"
                                     ));
```